# How can I block all pop-ups with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, popups

Some Websites (often links to 2leep.com) have very annoing advertising: If I click on a link, they open a popup with their adds and open the link I'm interested in.

If I go to chrome://settings/content , I can see that all popups should be blocked. So why do I get some and how can I stop it? Perhaps with a chrome-extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably extension called *ad-block* should clear the case. It's avalaible on firefox and chrome ([https://chrome.google.com/extensions/](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)). By far it is the best extension out there dealing with ads in my opinion.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I deinstalled adblock and flashblock after having recognized a strange issue on ebay: http://martin-thoma.blogspot.com/2011/02/ebay-and-chrome.html

Comment: ad block doesn't do it

Comment: Sounds like you have some adware. I would recommend removing any dubious browser add-ons and check your programs list for carp entries. Also a good Maharashtra scan wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2):

A site I visit produces pop-ups and I decided to look into why. I discovered that my Chrome already disallowed pop-ups (Settings > Show advanced settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Pop-ups), so what was going on?

I didn't find many pages on this particular problem via a general search, except for this forum:

http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/travel-technology/1448283-most-effective-way-blocking-pop-ups-google-chrome.html

The advice there was that if Chrome's normal pop=up blocker did not work, the issue probably was malware. I was not quick to this probability.

The other advice (as above) was to install Adblock and/or Flashbock. They take care of different problems, in my opinion, and I was not satisfied.

I decided to take matters into my own hands and figured there surely must be a pop-up blocking add-on to supplement Chrome's faulty one. At the Chrome store (I think that's where it was... lots of clicking around, you know), where it allows one to "shop" for other extensions, I typed in the keywords "pop-up blocker," and nothing of relevance came up. (Ditto for simply "pop-up" and also for "blocker." Boy, Chrome's built in pop-up blocker must have been perfect, if there were no such extensions developed anywhere.)

Before giving up, I gave it a shot on a regular Google search, and there was... "Better Pop-up blocker":

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-pop-up-blocker/nmpeeekfhbmikbdhlpjbfmnpgcbeggic

In fact, after adding it just now, once this "Better" one was installed, a page came up with a whole bunch of what was called "Related" other extensions, such as, "Classic Popup Blocker," "JavaScript Popup Blocker," "Pop Up Block Pro," "Poper Blocker" (not a typo on my part)... well, that was more like it.

Since I already installed "Better Pop-up blocker" and didn't have a chance to research whether any of the others might be potentially better, I'll first see how it goes. The developer took the time to address questions at the [program's web site](http://optimalcycling.com/other-projects/better-pop-up-blocker/) (at least in 2010)…

... And that made me think he was at least down-to-earth, giving me a false sense of confidence in the product. I just tested it once, and "Better Pop-up blocker" did take care of the pop-ups of the site I regularly visit. We shall see how well it behaves, otherwise... what;s next on that list above? "Classic Popup Blocker"!

.

Comment: I've added the link for you.

Comment: The second link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Chrome application on your PC.
2. Go to the "Settings" menu. Scroll down to the bottom of the window.
3. Click Show Advanced Settings Link.
4. Click on the "Content Settings" button under the "Privacy" section.
5. Scroll Down and Go to the "Pop-ups" tab.
6. Check the radio button next to "Do not allow any site to show pop-ups".
7. Click "Done" to save the settings.

Google Chrome will now block pop-up windows on all websites. Watch this tutorial: [How to Block Pop Ups in Google Chrome Browser?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvQEIK_VrBg) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently FlashBlock works quite well, check http://www.chromeextensions.org/appearance-functioning/flashblock/.